# Simple ASP.NET Core Web API - cannot implicitly convert type system.threading.tasks.task<microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.IAction>

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

Error occurs on line

```
MyWeatherData = WeatherAPI.GetMyWeather();
```

Error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.IAction>

I never used MVC before and I am getting confused on flow of MVC. Currently, from `view`, I am calling `HomeController`. Then from `HomeController`, I am calling 2nd `WeatherController`. I know this is wrong but now sure how to do this without creating so many controllers

What I am trying to do: I have a view (index), where I have a button. If button is clicked, I want to use the weather API to get the data, save in model class, and display the data in a view (`index`).

`Index.cshtml` file: this view has a button. if you click on it, it will send a post request to `HomeController`

```
<form asp-controller="Home" method="post">
        <button type="submit" >Submit</button>
</form>
// Display weather data here on click
```

HomeController class

```
    public WeatherModel MyWeatherData { get; set; } = default!;
    public WeatherController WeatherAPI { get; set;  }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        MyWeatherData = WeatherAPI.GetMyWeather();
        return View();
    }
```

WeatherController class

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class WeatherController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetMyWeather()
    {
        var latitude = 40.712776;
        var longitude = -74.005974;

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            try
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.open-meteo.com");
                var response = await client.GetAsync($"/v1/forecast?latitude={latitude}&longitude={longitude}&hourly=temperature_2m");
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                var stringResult = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); //get json data in string 
                var rawWeather = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<WeatherModel>(stringResult);

                WeatherModel WM = new WeatherModel();
                WM.latitude = rawWeather.latitude;
                WM.longitude = rawWeather.longitude;
                WM.generationtime_ms = rawWeather.generationtime_ms;
                WM.utc_offset_seconds = rawWeather.utc_offset_seconds;
                WM.timezone = rawWeather.timezone;
                WM.timezone_abbreviation = rawWeather.timezone_abbreviation;
                WM.elevation = rawWeather.elevation;
                
                return Ok(WM);
            }
            catch (HttpRequestException httpRequestException)
            {
                return BadRequest($"Error getting weather from OpenWeather: {httpRequestException.Message}");
            }
    }
}  //end of method
```

Model class

```
public class WeatherModel
{
    public long latitude { get; set; }
    public long longitude { get; set; }
    public long generationtime_ms { get; set; }
    public long utc_offset_seconds { get; set; }

    public string timezone { get; set; }
    public string timezone_abbreviation { get; set; }
    public string elevation { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MyWeatherData` is type of `WeatherModel` while the return type of `GetMyWeather` is `Task<IActionResult>`. That is why you get such compilation error.

Change your code like below:

HomeController

**Note:** you need initialize the `WeatherController`, otherwise you will get the null exception when you run the code.

```
public WeatherModel MyWeatherData { get; set; } = default!;
public WeatherController WeatherAPI { get; set; } = new WeatherController(); //change here....

public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    MyWeatherData = await WeatherAPI.GetMyWeather();  //add await...
    return View();
}
```

WeatherController

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class WeatherController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<WeatherModel> GetMyWeather()  //change the type to `Task<WeatherModel>`
    {
        var latitude = 40.712776;
        var longitude = -74.005974;

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            try
            {
                //...
                return WM;  //change here...
            }
            catch (HttpRequestException httpRequestException)
            {    
                //also change here...
                throw new Exception($"Error getting weather from OpenWeather: {httpRequestException.Message}");   
            }
        }
    }  
}
```

---

### Some suggestion

1.No need set the value for each property of the `WeatherModel WM = new WeatherModel();`, the data `rawWeather` you get is actually a type of `WeatherModel`. Just change your code:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<WeatherModel> GetMyWeather()
{
    var latitude = 40.712776;
    var longitude = -74.005974;

    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        try
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.open-meteo.com");
            var response = await client.GetAsync($"/v1/forecast?latitude={latitude}&longitude={longitude}&hourly=temperature_2m");
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            var stringResult = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); //get json data in string 
            var rawWeather = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<WeatherModel>(stringResult);

            return rawWeather;   //just return rawWeather....
        }
        catch (HttpRequestException httpRequestException)
        {
            throw new Exception($"Error getting weather from OpenWeather: {httpRequestException.Message}");
        }
    }
}
```

2.`var latitude = 40.712776;`,`var longitude = -74.005974;` are type of `long` and `hourly` is string type, be sure the api you called by HttpClient should contain parameter with (`long latitude, long longitude, string hourly`). If the type does not match, you will get the 400 error.

For example:

```
[Route("/v1/forecast")]
public IActionResult Get(double latitude, double longitude,string hourly)
{
    var model = new WeatherModel()
    {
        latitude = Convert.ToInt64(latitude),
        longitude = Convert.ToInt64(longitude),
        //...
    };
    return Json(model);
}
```

Comment: thanks i finally understand how to use web api and handle json data

Answer (score 0):

You're asking a few different questions here but it seems like ultimately you want to know how to resolve the compilation issue.

As you can see in your `WeatherController` action, it is async which is indicated by the `async` keyword as well as the `Task` type.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetMyWeather()
```

`Task<IActionResult>` means that you must await the response in order to get the response of type `IActionResult`. In order to do this, you should change your HomeController action to be async as well:

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    MyWeatherData = await WeatherAPI.GetMyWeather();
    return View();
}
```